# Customizing Accounting and finance module in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am working on Accounting and Finance module, I want to do some modifications like hiding fields and hiding Chart of Taxes. Can you anybody help me out?

[image]

Please tell me the procedure to hide left side menu item (Chart of taxes).

Also I want to know `view_id` to hide taxes from invoice sheet and at bottom Tax (update).

Please just let me know the external ids to hide them I am unable to find them as they were linked to some other models.

Invoice/Taxes field:

```
field_id:tax_id
```

object:

```
type:many2many
relation:account.tax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all activate **Odoo developer Mode**, so you can easily get the external ids of any objects.

[Activate Odoo Developer Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836304/how-to-activate-openerp-developer-mode/32836764#32836764)

**How to know External ID of any object**

Open that form and you can see one drop down field on top of the page only if the **developer mode** is active.

And select option "Edit Form View" from the drop down and you can see the details of that form view like model name, external id of that view and many more.

[image: Account Form View with Debug mode]

In your case to inherit this form use **"account.invoice_supplier_form"** external id of this form, see this image.
[image]

To know the **External Id** of **Menu Items**,

> Go to Settinsgs => Technical => User Interface => Menu Items

Search menu name that you want, open that record and select **View Metadata** from the debug mode drop down.
[image]

**How to hide Menu Items:**

To hide menu items there is one easiest way is to do this by creating new group (in which only specified user can have access) and assign that group to the menu item while you re-define that menu.

Create one group using xml file this must be first added in **__openerp__.py**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <record id="new_group_id" model="res.groups">
      <field name="name">New Group Name</field>
      <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_hidden"/>
      <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

And create another xml file in which is update that menu item with that xml code.

```
<record id="account.menu_action_tax_code_tree" model="ir.ui.menu">
  <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('new_group_id')] )]"/>
</record>
```

Another way is to do this from UI, directly assign that newly created group to menu items 
**Go to Settings => Technical => User Interface => Menu Items** (it's rollback while module will be upgrade in which that menu item defines).

**How to hide fields in existing view**

TO hide/add any fields in the existing form you must be inherit that view first and find that field using xpath or direct field and assign attributes to hide that field.

**Example:**

```
<record id="new_id" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">New.name</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_supplier_form" />
  <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <data>
    <!-- path according to the fields that you want to hide from tree -->
      <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='line_cr_ids']/tree/field[@name='account_id']" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="invisible">True/1</attribute>
      </xpath>

      <field name="tax_line" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="invisible">True/1</attribute>
      </field>
    </data>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: In my custom.xml file only i can do this no?? to hide menu item 

<menuitem id="account.menu_action_tax_code_tree" name="Chart of Taxes" groups="account.new_group_id"/>

or else should i do it in another group?? like below

<record id="account.menu_action_tax_code_tree" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('new_group_id')] )]"/>
</record>

<menuitem id="account.menu_action_tax_code_tree" name="Chart of Taxes" groups="account.new_group_id"/>

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<openerp>
    <data>

<record id="account.menu_action_tax_code_tree" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('new_group_id')] )]"/>
</record>

<menuitem id="account.menu_action_tax_code_tree" name="Chart of Taxes" groups="account.new_group_id"/>

 </data>
</openerp>